# What does "[chS]" mean in the regex of this shell command?

Tags: shell, grep

```
egrep -r --include "*.[chS]" "myregularexpression" .
```

What does `[chS]` mean in the shell command above?

Comment: You would have gotten a hint from looking at the man-page for `egrep`.  It mentions that the `--include` argument parameter is a glob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is part of the shell globbing that selects multiple files.

The expression `[chS]` matches a single character containing the value `c`, `h`, or `S`.

So, the glob `"*.[chS]"` is looking for all files that have the extension `.c`, `.h`, or `.s`

Answer (score 2):

`[chS]` is a character class and is equivalent to the expression `c|h|S`. It matches any one of the listed characters. In this case, `*.[chS]` is matching files `(*.c, or *.h or *.S)`, i.e., C source and headers, and assembly files.